# Trying to make a cURL request in PHP with ---location parameter

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I want to cURL the following request in PHP:

`curl --location --request GET 'xxx.xxxxxad.com/api/rest/issues?project_id=4' -H 'Authorization:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHTb'`

The code that I implemented was:

```
<?php  

$url = "xxx.xxxxxad.com/api/rest/issues?project_id=4";  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array('Authorization:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHTb'));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

$output = curl_exec($ch);  

echo $output;

curl_close($ch);  

?>
```

I cannot find a way to include `--location` in the request without which the data cannot be fetched.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. please, check first sentence you used.

Comment: Go read up on what `--location` _does_, then go read the manual page for PHP curl_setopt, and try to figure out what the equivalent is …? You probably want `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

Comment: Also go change your access key, because it shouldn't be hard for someone who _really_ wanted to, or is just _really_ bored, to figure out which domain you're using, and now they have your access key. (editing your post won't suffice - SO has an edit history)

Answer (score 0):

`--request GET` roughly translates to `CURLOPT_HTTPGET=>1` (actually the strict translation is CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, but don't do that, it's usually a bad idea leading to bugs down the road if/when you try to re-use the curl handle for other stuff in the future and forget to reset it - CUSTOMREQUEST is bug-prone, as a rule of thumb: avoid it where possible.)

also `CURLOPT_HEADER` does something completely different (you can read about it here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADER.html )  , what you need to actually set custom headers is `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`, in short:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxHTb'
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL => 'xxx.xxxxxad.com/api/rest/issues?project_id=4'
));
```